# Perforce mark for delete command and reverting back timings

Tags: perforce

I am using Windows 7, perforce 2010.2 Yellow client.

I was trying to mark some 6 files for deletion. But accidently, it marked the entire depot for for deletion (could be my mistake).

But strange behavior is it marked for delete in less than a second (more than 1,00,000 files), but reverting took more than 5 hours.

Does anybody know how it works internally? Or any guesses?

Comment: Reverting a deleted file requires redownloading it from the server, so it's naturally going to be slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As James said, the p4 delete removed all 1,000,000 files. Reverting that requires the client to re-download all 1,000,000 files.

Comment: I agree to the point that it Perforce had to download all the files from server and as they were more, it took time. But how come it marked these many files just in less than a second. I am sure, it had to pass the marking for deletion information to server and server had to apply that to the entire depot, that should have taken lot of time. Similarly it had to remove that files from my machine, even this process should have taken lot of time. But magic part is all this happened in less than a second.

Comment: My experience having run p4 delete accidentally more than a few times in my career is deleting files is extremely fast when they don't have to go into the "Recycle Bin" or "Trash". When I do this from the command line it takes longer to display all the text in my terminal than it does to actually remove the files.